# Restrict function return value to void

Tags: typescript

`bar` is expected to be a function with no return value:

```
let foo = () => 'foo';
let bar: () => void = foo; // produces no error
```

Can `bar` be prevented from being assigned with a function that doesn't match expected `() => void` signature?

For example, in this case:

```
declare let jsApiThatShouldNeverAcceptTypeofFoo = (bar: () => void) => void;
jsApiThatShouldNeverAcceptTypeofFoo(bar);
```

Comment: See [this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8581)

Comment: @nonexplosive Sweet. *Working as Intended*. I just hope that there may be a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial workaround is to ensure that the return type of the function has no keys. This is satisfied by `void`, but also by `{}` and `never`. This might be close enough, as functions retuning `never` should throw an error and functions returning `{}` happen infrequently enough:

```
type EnsureVoid<T> = keyof T extends never ? 
    void 
    : "Should not have a return type, only ()=> void is allowed";

declare let jsApiThatShouldNeverAcceptTypeofFoo: <T extends EnsureVoid<T>>(bar: ()=> T) => void;

let foo = () => 'foo';
jsApiThatShouldNeverAcceptTypeofFoo(foo)  // Error 


let bar = () => { };
jsApiThatShouldNeverAcceptTypeofFoo(bar)


let baz = () => ({ });
jsApiThatShouldNeverAcceptTypeofFoo(baz)

let boo = () => { throw "Error" };
jsApiThatShouldNeverAcceptTypeofFoo(boo)
```

Comment: Neat. Won't work for null, but it's better than nothing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, because a void returning function is assignable to a value returning function. On the other hand, you can't use the return value if you expected a void returning function. i.e.

```
let foo = () => 'foo';
let bar: () => void = foo; // produces no error

const result = bar(); // foo in runtime, TypeScript thinks it's void
const upper = result.toUpperCase(); // compile error
```

Comment: Sadly, `result` type check won't work if bar is called inside non-TS code. This is the problem I'm trying to address.

Comment: Then, this [transpiler](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20foo%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20'foo'%3B%0D%0Alet%20bar%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%20%3D%20foo%3B%20%2F%2F%20produces%20no%20error%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20result%20%3D%20bar()%3B%20%2F%2F%20foo%20in%20runtime%2C%20compile%20error.%0D%0Aconsole.log(result)%3B) must have it wrong, though it does give a transpilation error when using the `toUpperCase`